# Getting text value from input field using TagsInput

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the input value from a text field while using TagsInput Library.

This is my html field

```
<input class="tagsinput form-control" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" id="tagsinput"/>
```

This is what i am using to create the tags.

```
$('.tagsinput').tagsinput({
  trimValue: true,
  tagClass: 'label label-primary',
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'organizationtags',
    display: 'name',
    valueKey: 'name',
    source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  }
});
```

But i can only get the value in the text box when a "tag" is created like below

[image]

This is how i am getting the value and assigning it to an array 
 [image]

But when i just type the word without hitting enter to create the tag like so: 
[image]

the value is not added to the array because it is not a "tag"..

Therefore what i am trying to achieve is a tag being created once i hit the add button. Without needing to hit enter to create the actual tag.